# How sort in array with exception

Tags: swift

How to sort this array by distance eg:

```
[(id: 1, type: .normal, distance: 10), (id: 2, type: .inter, distance: 10), (id: 3, type: .inter, distance: 80), (id: 4, type: .inter, distance: 20),  (id: 5, type: .normal, distance: 100)]

sorted(by: { $0.distance < $1.distance })
```

But how to make an exception to sort only .inter and .normal left unchanged.

Comment: What do you mean unchanged? Are inter value always between two normal? Is the first and the last alway a normal? Because if that's the case, make a "sub" array (drop first and last), sort it, and reput first and last.

Answer (score 0):

If the ‘id’ is always sorted when you want to start sort using ‘id’ in case of same distance

```
{ 
    if ($0.distance == $1.distance) {
        return $0.id < $1.id
    } else {
       return $0.distance < $1.distance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an array, not a dictionary. And you can achieve your goal like this:

```
let array = [(id: 1, type: .normal, distance: 10), (id: 2, type: .inter, distance: 10), (id: 3, type: .inter, distance: 80), (id: 4, type: .inter, distance: 20),  (id: 5, type: .normal, distance: 100)]

let sortedArray = array.sorted {
    guard $0.type == .inter && $1.type == .inter else { return false }
    return $0.distance < $1.distance
}
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, array of course (edited).